# Django template tag that takes in a boolean and returns html

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this bit of HTML that is going to be used in multiple places.

```
            {% if event.finished_payments %}
            <span class="label label-success">Complete</span>
            {% else %}
            <span class="label label-important">Incomplete</span>
            {% endif %}
```

I want to write a template tag that takes in a bool and returns `<span class="label label-success">Complete</span>` or `<span class="label label-important">Incomplete</span>` depending on whether the argument is `True` or `False` which I suppose looks something like this:

{% tf_label event.finished_payments %}

Alternatively, is another way of achieving this using the `include` template tag and pass in parameters?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick (not tested):

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def tf_label(request, complete):
    if complete:
        element = '<span class="label label-success">Complete</span>'
    else
        element = '<span class="label label-important">Incomplete</span>'

    return element
```

Answer (score 5):

```
{{ event.finished_payments|yesno:"<span class='label label-success'>Complete</span>,<span class='label label-important'>Incomplete</span>" }}
```

But it think, using `{% if %}` tag is the best idea here, it's more readable. Anyway HTML should live in templates, not in Python code.

Comment: Nice solution. Another option would be an inclusion tag. It could be considered more readable/verbose than the yesno-filter and the html is contained in a template.